# how to return row values of a column such that their corresponding value in another column are the smallest n values, in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, max, r-rownames

I have df below.

```
df<-cbind(c("LA", "NY", "Rome"),c(1,1,2),c(0,1,0),c(0,1,2),c(1,3,4))
     [city] [c1] [c2] [c3] [sum]
[1,] "LA"   "1"  "0"  "0"  "1" 
[2,] "NY"   "1"  "1"  "1"  "3" 
[3,] "Rome" "2"  "0"  "2"  "4"
```

I want to compare the values in sum column to find the two smallest values .( here 1,3 in increasing order)
then return the corresponding values in city column with the same order. 
so what I want in out put is : `LA, NY`

I can get the rownames ( which I do not want, but I do not know how to get LA, NY:

```
rownames(df$city[order(df$sum, decreasing = F),][1:2])[1:2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataset in the question is a `matrix` (`cbind` returns a matrix by default and matrix can have only a single type.  Thus, the whole dataset is converted to `character`).  If we need to extract 'n' elements of first column based on the last column (5th column), extract the 5th column, convert to `numeric`, use `order` to get the index of values in ascending order, then with `head` get the `n` order index and use that to subset the first column

```
n <- 2
df[,1][head(order(as.numeric(df[,5])), n)]
[1] "LA" "NY"
```

---

`as.data.frame(cbind` is wrong way as the columns are already getting type changed to `character`.  It is better to use `data.frame` directly

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = ..., col2 = .., col3 = ...)
```

Comment: thanks you! I just selected this answer since maybe for other beginners like myself, this is less complicated to apply.

Answer (score 1):

By `tidyverse` style,

```
(df%>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  arrange(sum) %>%
  pull(city))[1:2]

[1] "LA" "NY"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(city = c("LA", "NY", "Rome"),
                 c1 = c(1,1,2),
                 c2 = c(0,1,0),
                 c3 = c(0,1,2),
                 sum = c(3,1,4))
```

We could use the `%in%` operator to extract a logical index of matches, and use that to subset your city variable:

```
df$city[ df$sum %in% sort(df$sum)[1:2] ]
[1] "LA" "NY"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr`'s `filter`, to extract only those rows in which sum is `%in%` the top (`head`) two sum values, then `pull` the city vector

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(sum %in% head(sum, 2)) %>% pull(city)
[1] "LA" "NY"
```